# How do sugars react with cobalt(II) and ammonia?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates

I did an experiment regarding the identification of a range of monosaccharides and disaccharides and wanted to know what the exact purpose of this experiment was and what is was testing.

The following steps were carried out:

1. Add 10 mL of 5% solution of fructose, glucose and sucrose to separate test tubes.
2. Add 4mL of cobalt (II) chloride to each test tube.
3. Heat each test tube to near boiling, then cool.
4. Add 8 drops of ammonia to each test tube.
5. Record any colour changes.

Fructose was the only one with an observable colour change. 
Why / how does the fructose behave differently from other saccharides? Is it because fructose breaks down in a different way from the other sugars?